# How do i get the host name from a URL in my case?

Tags: javascript

what I am trying to achieve is get the host name from a URL and determine which type of environment.
Right now i have two websites which I need to determine.

This is one website

```
https://dev.example.com/xx.html
```

The other web site is

```
 https://www.example.com/xx.html
```

all i need is to make a variable true if dev is present in the start or else false

How do i proceed and determine which is dev and which is not dev website

Comment: Check this up [get-domain-name-url-javascript](https://w3collective.com/get-domain-name-url-javascript/)

Comment: `window.location.host.split('.')[0]`

Comment: @Keith thats a very good method.Thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) with [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) like:

```js
//const url = new URL(window.location) <-- in your website;
const urlDev = new URL('https://dev.example.com/xx.html');
const url = new URL('https://www.example.com/xx.html');
console.log(url.host.includes('dev.'), urlDev.host.includes('dev.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to `window.location` properties : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hostname

But the clean way to do that is to use ENV variables ;)

Comment: Sure will take a look at it <3

Answer (score 1):

It is considered good practice to mark the version of an application at the build stage, but yeah, here an example

```
const parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = window.location.href;
const hostname = parser.hostname;

// Check if the hostname starts with "dev."
const isDev = hostname.startsWith("dev.");

isDev ? console.log("This is a dev website.") : console.log("This is not a dev website.");
```